# how to get linkedin page views count through rest api

Tags: linkedin-api

In linkedin how can we get the page views count through API. There is no API for this in developer document, if any idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Get statistics for a company page" using LinkedIn REST API.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#statistics

```
"statusUpdateStatistics": {
"viewsByMonth": {
  "_total": 1,
  "values": [
    {
      "clicks": 81333,
      "comments": 1203,
      "date": {
        "month": 1,
        "year": 2015
      },
      "engagement": 0.003203537929382338,
      "impressions": 32797489,
      "likes": 20387,
      "shares": 2145
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, since i have to get the unique visitors count for the company page